# Как поставить кнопку между двумя инпутами

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

У меня не получается вставить между инпутами кнопку со стрелками. Как это можно выправить, подскажите пожалуйста.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
          <h1>Want to Send Money?</h1>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="currency-sorting">
              <div>
                <label>From</label>
                <input type="search" class="form-control"> 
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span>
              </button>
              <div>
                <label>To</label>
                <input type="search" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-default form-control">Set Rate Alerts</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-default form-control" onclick="window.location.href='/company-rates.html'">Search Best Rate</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8 ">
          <div class="maps">
            <!-- <img src="img/world.png" alt=""> -->
            <div id="vmap"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Схема, как должно быть. (Немного кривовата, но суть должна быть ясна)
[image: схема]

Comment: Обратите внимание: 1) в конце вашего кода не хватало одного закрывающего `</div>`; 2) перед скриптами Бутстрапа надо загрузить jQuery, иначе они не заработают; 3) страница грузится быстрее, когда скрипты стоят последними, перед  `</body>'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать их инлайн-блоками. И дать им побольше места, чтобы они поместились в одной строке.

```css
.currency-sorting .form-group {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1>Want to Send Money?</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="currency-sorting">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>From</label>
            <input type="search" class="form-control"> 
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>To</label>
            <input type="search" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default form-control">Set Rate Alerts</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default form-control" onclick="window.location.href='/company-rates.html'">Search Best Rate</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 ">
      <div class="maps">
        <!-- <img src="img/world.png" alt=""> -->
        <div id="vmap"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```